# I am getting an error "Snipcart.api.setCurrency is not a function", I think it might be from the Accept: application/json

Tags: jquery, json, api, squarespace, snipcart

I am helping someone integrate Snipcart into their Squarespace store and they want to use the multi-currency functionality. I am getting an error "Snipcart.api.setCurrency is not a function" for every Snipcart.api... function I have.

I think it might have to do with not having "Accept: application/json" included in my code but I don't know where and how to use it.

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('snipcart.ready', function(){
    console.log('ready!');
      Snipcart.subscribe('cart.ready', function() {
        $('#currency').val(Snipcart.api.getCurrentCurrency());
      });

      Snipcart.subscribe('currency.changed', function (currency) {
        $('#currency').val(currency);
      });

      $(function() {
        $('#currency').change(function () {
          Snipcart.api.setCurrency($(this).val());
        });
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Check the docs, are you sure that method exists? I can't see any mention of it. The closest I can find is `Snipcart.api.cart.currency(currencyShortCode);`, https://docs.snipcart.com/javascript-api-reference/public-api#currency

Comment: All the code has been pulled from their website https://snipcart.com/blog/multi-currency-display-checkout-online-store

Comment: That blog post is 3 years old, the code may be out of date.

Comment: That is completely true and probably one of the many problems I am having. From part of the docs https://docs.snipcart.com/configuration/multi-currency I am struggling to understand this: "This method should be called when you load the page. You must be able to know in which currency your application is set when calling the method. This can be done using a URL query string parameter, cookies, or any other technique you might think of."

Comment: Which part are you struggling with? Its saying that you need to call that method needs to be called immediately when the page loads to set the default currency.

Comment: Now I am stuck on trying to: "You must be able to know in which currency your application is set when calling the method. This can be done using a URL query string parameter, cookies, or any other technique you might think of." Not sure how to get the information I need and how to use URL query string parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but for the ones that still get stuck, here is the code (used on snipcart v3.0.31). Note that the cart won't auto update when you change currency.

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('snipcart.ready', function() {
    
    const select = document.getElementById('currencies');
    select.addEventListener('change', () => {
    Snipcart.api.session.setCurrency(select.value);
    });
    
    Snipcart.store.subscribe(updateSelectedCurrency);

    function updateSelectedCurrency() {
        const state = Snipcart.store.getState();
        const currency = state.cart.currency;
    document.getElementById('currencies').value = currency;
    }
});                                                                           
</script>
```